# difference SAFE_RELEASE(), SAFE_DELETE()

Tags: c++, c, directx

I'm newbie in programming.

I'm wondering release and delete function.

When I allocate memory with new, I should terminate it with delete.

But when I should use release?

What's the difference release and delete...?

Comment: where are SAFE_RELEASE and SAFE_DELETE defined they are not part of standard C or C++

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for definition you will find

```
#define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if ( (p) ) { (p)->Release(); (p) = 0; } }
#define SAFE_DELETE(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete (a); (a) = NULL;
```

SAFE_DELETE should be used for memory allocated with new

SAFE_RELEASE should be called for com objects (like directx objects) and "under the hood" is doind something like this

```
if (--ref_cnt==0)
{
   delete this;
}
```

it decrements a reference counter and releases the object if there are no more references to it.

Comment: Oh, marvelous, `SAFE_DELETE` will null the pointer to make sure we do not access unduly to the object it pointed too...

Answer (score 5):

c++ has no release, perhaps you saw that in a tutorial involving COM+? Like DirectX?

Certainly, `SAFE_RELEASE` and `SAFE_DELETE` are not actually part of c++ and are likely to be macros defined in some header file.

Anyway, here's the rules:

- `delete[]` what you `new[]`
- `delete` what you `new`
- `free()` what you `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`